# Can Rational Composed with Non-Rational Function Be Rational?

Tags: analysis, polynomials

Suppose $f(z)$ is continuous and surjective onto $\mathbb{C}$, but not rational. Let $R$ and $Q$ be non-constant rational functions. Can we have $R(f(z))=Q(z)$?
Clearly this is possible if $R$ and $Q$ can be constant. This came up in something I was working on and I want to say no but can’t prove it. Specifically I want to know if there can be a rational $R$ such that
$$R(z)=\frac{1}{f(z)}+R(f(z))$$
In case that has a different answer from the general case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Let $f(z) = z^{m/n}$ and $R(z) = Q(z^n)$ for any rational function $Q$. If $n\nmid m$, then $f(z)$ is not rational but both $R(z)$ and $R(f(z)) = Q(z^m)$ are rational.

If $m > n$, then setting $\operatorname{dom}(f) = \Bbb C \setminus (-\infty, 0)$ and choosing the principal branch of $\sqrt[n]z$ provides a continuous surjective function.

Comment: Ah of course thank you. Can anything be said about it if we add that $f$ can not be rational in a power of $z$?

Comment: That only requires $f$ to be the inverse of a more complicated polynomial applied to $x^m$. You can still manipulate it to satisfy your requirements. Really, your question amounts to asking "Do rational functions $R$ and $Q$ exist such that $R$ has a local inverse making $R^{-1}\circ Q$ surjective?" And the answer simply amounts to finding the right domain for the inverse.

Comment: Actually, I have to take that last comment back: if the polynomial is more complicated, then it no longer has an inverse that is both continuous and surjective. You can have one or the other, but not both. It might be possible with rational functions that are not linear (for fractional linear functions, $f$ would be rational).